# Can a web crawler distinguish encodings?

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup, character-encoding, web-crawler

**Can a web crawler distinguish encodings ?**

I am building a crawler to gather some data. However, it looks the website I'm searching through is not properly encoded; the charset is utf-8, but some of the text seems to be in latin-1.

As an example you can run the code below. I'll use a Polish name and a Spanish name that both have special characters as examples.
If I copy-paste them and print them, the IDE in utf-8 prints them correctly.
However if I scrape from the website, Adrian's name doesn't print properly. But if I encode the string in latin-1, it does.

So I guess some text on the website is not utf-8 and is latin-1. The problem is how do I tell my crawler whether or not it needs to encode the text in latin-1 ? If I try to encode everything, names like Pawel's return errors. Should I use a try/else ?

```py
# coding = utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

def download_soup(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)
    page = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    return soup

print('utf-8 : Paweł Cieślik')
print('utf-8 : Adrián González')
pawel_soup = download_soup('https://www.procyclingstats.com/rider/pawel-cieslik').find('title').text
adrian_soup = download_soup('https://www.procyclingstats.com/rider/adrian-gonzalez').find('title').text
print('web original encoding : '+pawel_soup)
print('web original encoding : '+adrian_soup)
print('web latin encoding : '+adrian_soup.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
```

Returns

```
utf-8 : Paweł Cieślik
utf-8 : Adrián González
web original encoding : Paweł Cieślik
web original encoding : AdriÃ¡n GonzÃ¡lez
web latin encoding : Adrián González
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error when you try to encode unicode by latin-1, you can pass parameter to ignore it:

```
pawel_soup.encode('latin-1', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8')
```